# Find the least number of moves to cause the least damage

Tags: java

The problem statement is this:

An alien robot is threatening the universe, using a beam that will destroy all algorithms knowledge. We have to stop it!

Fortunately, we understand how the robot works. It starts off with a beam with a strength of 1, and it will run a program that is a series of instructions, which will be executed one at a time, in left to right order. Each instruction is of one of the following two types:

C (for "charge"): Double the beam's strength.
S (for "shoot"): Shoot the beam, doing damage equal to the beam's current strength.
For example, if the robot's program is SCCSSC, the robot will do the following when the program runs:

Shoot the beam, doing 1 damage.
Charge the beam, doubling the beam's strength to 2.
Charge the beam, doubling the beam's strength to 4.
Shoot the beam, doing 4 damage.
Shoot the beam, doing 4 damage.
Charge the beam, increasing the beam's strength to 8.
In that case, the program would do a total of 9 damage.

The universe's top algorithmists have developed a shield that can withstand a maximum total of D damage. But the robot's current program might do more damage than that when it runs.

The President of the Universe has volunteered to fly into space to hack the robot's program before the robot runs it. The only way the President can hack (without the robot noticing) is by swapping two adjacent instructions. For example, the President could hack the above program once by swapping the third and fourth instructions to make it SCSCSC. This would reduce the total damage to 7. Then, for example, the president could hack the program again to make it SCSSCC, reducing the damage to 5, and so on.

To prevent the robot from getting too suspicious, the President does not want to hack too many times. What is this smallest possible number of hacks which will ensure that the program does no more than D total damage, if it is possible to do so?

My code currently computes the smallest number of hacks after swapping every adjacent character in the string. However, this does not cover all the possibilities to create the smallest number of hacks **N** required to have damage <= damage that shield can withstand. **What algorithm would be required to go through every possibility and find the smallest number of hacks required?** My code is below for reference.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        int t = scan.nextInt(); // number of test cases
        for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
            long maximumDamage = 0; // stores maximum damage that the shield can withstand
            maximumDamage = scan.nextLong();
            String program = "";
            program = scan.next();
            int numHacks = 0; // computes the number of hacks required
            char[] programArr = program.toCharArray();
            // computes the minimum number of hacks required
            if (damageComputer(program) <= maximumDamage) {
                System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + 0);
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < program.length() - 1; j++) {
                    char temp = 'a'; // stores one of the characters at position j
                    temp = programArr[j];
                    programArr[j] = programArr[j + 1];
                    programArr[j + 1] = temp;
                    numHacks++;
                    program = new String(programArr);
                    if (damageComputer(program) <= maximumDamage) {
                        System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + numHacks);
                        break;
                    } 

                }
            }
        }
    }

    // computes the total damage that a program will yield
    public static long damageComputer(String program) {
        long strength = 1; // Starts with 1 because initial strength of beam is 1
        long damage = 0; // computes the current damage that the program will yield. 
        char[] programArr = program.toCharArray();
        // computes the total damage 
        for (int i = 0; i < program.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (programArr[i] == 'C') {
                strength = strength * 2;
            } else {
                damage = damage + strength; 
            }
        }
        return damage;
    }

}
```

**EDIT: Works for most test cases, but gets stuck in an infinite loop for some other cases**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        int t = scan.nextInt(); // number of test cases
        for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
            long maximumDamage = 0; // stores maximum damage that the shield can withstand
            maximumDamage = scan.nextLong();
            String program = "";
            String newProgram = "";
            program = scan.next();
            boolean hackCompleted = true;
            int numHacks = 0; // computes the number of hacks required
            char[] programArr = program.toCharArray();
            // computes the minimum number of hacks required
            if (damageComputer(program) <= maximumDamage) {
                System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + 0);
            } else {
                programArr = program.toCharArray();
                for (int k = 0; k < program.length() - 1; k++) {
                    newProgram = program;
                for (int j = 0; j <= program.length() - 1; j++) {
                    char temp = 'a'; // stores one of the characters at position j
                    if (contains(newProgram, "CS") > 0) {
                    int containsIndex = contains(newProgram, "CS") - 1;
                    temp = programArr[containsIndex];
                    programArr[containsIndex] = programArr[containsIndex + 1];
                    programArr[containsIndex + 1] = temp;
                    numHacks++;
                    newProgram = new String(programArr);
                    } else {
                        hackCompleted = false;
                    }
                    newProgram = new String(programArr);
                    if (damageComputer(newProgram) <= maximumDamage) {
                        System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + numHacks);
                        hackCompleted = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (hackCompleted == true && j != 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    if (hackCompleted == true) {
                        break;
                    }
                numHacks = 0;
                }

            if (hackCompleted == false) {
                System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + "IMPOSSIBLE");
            }
            }
        }
    }

    // computes the total damage that a program will yield
    public static long damageComputer(String program) {

        long strength = 1; // Starts with 1 because initial strength of beam is 1
        long damage = 0; // computes the current damage that the program will yield. 
        char[] programArr = program.toCharArray();
        // computes the total damage 
        for (int i = 0; i < program.length(); i++) {
            if (programArr[i] == 'C') {
                strength = strength * 2;
            } else {
                damage = damage + strength; 
            }
        }
        return damage;
    }

    public static int contains(String s1, String s2) {
        if(s1.length() < s2.length())
            return -1;

        int lastOccurrence = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); ) {
            if (s1.startsWith(s2, i)) {
                lastOccurrence = i + s2.length() - 1;
                i = lastOccurrence + 1;
            }
            else {
                ++i;
            }
        }
        return lastOccurrence;
    }

}
```

**FINAL UPDATE** The problem has been solved. Please view the selected solution along with comments for guidance. The test cases are here if you wanted to test your programs. All credits go to Google.

Input

6
1 CS
2 CS
1 SS
6 SCCSSC
2 CC
3 CSCSS

Output

Case #1: 1
Case #2: 0
Case #3: IMPOSSIBLE
Case #4: 2
Case #5: 0
Case #6: 5

Comment: Find rightmost occurrence of `SC` and swap it, continue till you either cannot swap anymore (ie SSSCCC) or D is reached

Comment: Could you explain to me what you mean by rightmost? Thank you.

Comment: Last occurrence of `CS` substring in string, not `SC`! I have typo in my first comment

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thanks so much man! It works now :) How did you know that this particular algorithm worked? That's what really is important :D

Comment: @Dylan Could you elaborate what was the problem and how you solved it?

Comment: @Dylan can you post some test cases?

Comment: @Naruto Sure, the problem was that I wasn't looping over all the possible permutations, and therefore, I wasn't getting the correct number of "hacks". In order to successfully solve this problem, I followed Ilya Bursov's advice and swapped every last "CS" string that was found around, and that's the simple trick :D

Comment: @IlyaBursov Yes,                                                                               
Input 
6 (6 test cases)
1 CS 
2 CS
1 SS
6 SCCSSC
2 CC
3 CSCSS
Output
Case #1: 1
Case #2: 0
Case #3: IMPOSSIBLE
Case #4: 2
Case #5: 0
Case #6: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To minimize number of hacks - each swap should reduce damage by maximal value possible, maximal can be achieve only if we swap last occurrence of 'CS' substring, ie swap charge-shoot with shoot-charge.

Here is a little bit modified version of your program which does this, its written in 2 minutes, so I could miss some edge cases.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution1 {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int t = scan.nextInt(); // number of test cases
        for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
            final long maximumDamage = scan.nextLong();
            final char[] a = scan.next().toCharArray();

            long minDamage = 0; for (final char c : a) if ('S' == c) minDamage++;

            if (maximumDamage >= minDamage) {
                long hacks = 0;
                while (damageComputer(a) > maximumDamage) {
                    int swappos;
                    while ((swappos = swappos(a)) >= 0) {
                        a[swappos] = 'S'; a[swappos + 1] = 'C'; hacks++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + hacks);
            } else
                System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + "IMPOSSIBLE");
        }
    }
    public static long damageComputer(final char[] a) {
        long strength = 1, damage = 0;
        for (final char c : a) if ('C' == c) strength <<= 1; else damage += strength;
        return damage;
    }
    public static int swappos(final char[] a) {
        for (int i = a.length - 2; i > 0; --i)
            if ((a[i] == 'C') && (a[i + 1] == 'S')) return i;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This advice was what guided me in the right direction, everybody! I encourage you not to copy the code directly, but to learn from it as the simple advice of switching every "CS" string with "SC" significantly helped me!